# Retrieving data with DataProtectionProvider

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, datacontractserializer

I'm developing a Windows 8/WinRT App and i encounter a problem to retrieve crypted data by using the `DataProtectionProvider`. To serialize data I'm using this:

```
internal static async Task SerializeFileEncrypted<T>(T type, StorageFile file)
{
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(ms, type);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            DataProtectionProvider dpp = new DataProtectionProvider("Local=User");

            await dpp.ProtectStreamAsync(ms.AsInputStream(), stream.AsOutputStream());
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And to deserialize data I'm using this:

```
internal static async Task<T> DeserializeEncryptedFile<T>(StorageFile file)
{
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataProtectionProvider dpp = new DataProtectionProvider();
        await dpp.UnprotectStreamAsync((await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()).AsInputStream(), ms.AsOutputStream());
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Serializing process seems to works well but when I try to deserialize the file I have the following error: "Unexpected end of file."

I suspect the problem to be linked to the encoding of the file. When I don't crypt data and only use `DataContractSerializer` I have an UTF8 file whereas otherwise I have an ANSI file. Can someone help me to figure out where is my problem and how to solve it?

Comment: In fact I have an other problem. The error is not "Unexpected end of file". The problem is related where the DataProtectionProvider is executed. Those method were used in a Windows Runtime Component and the deserializer seem to not work here. When I put the deserializer in my main program, it work fine.